# How do I test this swap number function?

Tags: rust

I'm currently writing a simple function to swap numbers in Rust:

```
fn swapnumbers() {
    let a = 1;
    let b = 2;
    let (a, b) = (b, a);
    println!("{}, {}", a, b);
}
```

I am now trying to make a test for it, how do I do it? All my other attempts have failed.

Comment: That function, from a testing perspective, does not swap two numbers. It prints out `2, 1`, the constant string. The only thing you can test, given that this function takes no arguments and returns nothing, is that its output to stdout is correct. If you want to test the "swap" part, then this function should take arguments.

Comment: Unless, you’re testing the println macro, this function doesn’t do anything, so, there’s nothing to test.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I pointed that out in my answer but also provided a way for them to actually swap data.

Comment: This function would be a lot more useful if `fn swapnumbers(a: (i32,i32)) -> (i32,i32)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest modifying the function to return something instead of printing it, and then using either the `assert_eq!` or `assert!` macros to test for proper function. ([docs for assert_eq!](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.assert_eq.html), [docs for assert!](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.assert.html))

```rs
fn swapnumbers() -> (i32, i32) {
    let a = 1;
    let b = 2;
    let (a, b) = (b, a);
    return (a, b);
}

assert_eq!(swapnumbers(), (2, 1));
```

(`-> (i32, i32)` means that this function returns a tuple of two `i32`s)

And if you're unfamiliar with testing in Rust, the official [Rust book tutorial](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-01-writing-tests.html) can help you out with that!

If you want to actually swap numbers, you would need to do something like this:

```rs
fn swapnumbers(a: &mut i32, b: &mut i32) {
    std::mem::swap(a, b);
}
```

Note the types specified after the parameter names. `&mut i32` means the passed value must be a mutable reference of an `i32` The parameter must be mutable for you to be able to assign to it and change its value, and it must be a reference so that the function does not actually take ownership of the data.

Comment: I would also add a simple note about parameters in the function, and a sample explanation. +1 for the std::mem::swap()